# How does a web Accessibility Screenreader like ChromeVOX read paragraphs?

Tags: browser, accessibility, screen-reader

I migrated this question to SuperUser on the advice in an answer to the OP:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65161111/how-does-a-web-accessibility-screenreader-like-chromevox-read-paragraphs/65161406#65161406

If this is not the correct place to post, please advise.  The OP is below:

I am testing a site for accessibility using ChromeVOX and I notice that the

tag content does not get read. When I tab through the main content, ChromeVOX simply skips over the

and reads the <h#> tags, and links.

I have watched the video: https://youtu.be/OUDV1gqs9GA?t=2748 and at this section, the narrator skips to the first  and then mentions a hotkey that will just let the screenreader continue to read all the text. However, narrator does not mention what that hotkey is.

I have looked at the ChromeVOX keyboard shortcuts, but I cannot find that one:

http://apps4android.org/chromevox/chromevox_keyboard_shortcuts_ref.htm

Also, here is a link to a site to see how screen-readers work:

https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/accessibility/html/good-semantics.html

When I navigate that site with ChromeVOX, it also does not read anything except for the  tag.

So, what is the keyboard shortcut or method to read the content in the

tags or role="main" tag? Is there an aria tag that would include those paragraphs? As far as I can see, this behaviour is common across all sites.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Search</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> selects the next item on a Chrome Book, on everything else it is

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd>

To just start reading from the current cursor position it is

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>

[You may find this page more useful for shortcuts on ChromeVOX](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/7031755?hl=en-GB), wherever it says <kbd>Launcher</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Search</kbd> you just use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> on anything other than a ChromeBook.

Comment: I tried those keybindings and they did not work on Mac OS with Chrome browser and ChromeVOX. I was using this site to test: https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/accessibility/html/good-semantics.html

Comment: Those are the keys on Windows, I don't have a Mac at home. As far as I can tell though the keys are the same. Make sure you haven't switched on "sticky keys" by mistake (where you toggle screen reader mode on and off, in which case you only press the final modifier).